# Failed trying to insert my data

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I'm trying to insert some list into my Data base(Microsoft) but i got this run time error

> Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a Int32.

here's my code

```
  public void InsertInventory(DateTime _date, int _customer_Id,
                            int _employee_Id, List<int> _product_Id,
                            List<int> _amountSold,
                            List<int> _unitPrice, List<int> _totalPrice)
    {
        Connection_String = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog="
                           + "Sales and Inventory System"
                           + ";Integrated Security=TrueData Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog="
                           + "Sales and Inventory System"
                           + ";Integrated Security=True;";

        Query = "insert into Inventory" +
                  "(Customer_Id,Employee_Id,Product_Id,[Date],[Amount Sold],[Unit Price],[Total Price])" +
                    "values (@customer_id,@Employee_id,@Product_id,@[Date],@[Amount_Sold],@[Unit_Price],@[Total_Price])";

        using (Con = new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
        using (Cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Con))
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Employee_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product_id", SqlDbType.Int);
           //Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Date]", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Date]", SqlDbType.Date);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Amount_sold]", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Unit_Price]", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total_Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);

            Cmd.Connection = Con;
            Con.Open();

            int RecordToAdd = _product_Id.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < RecordToAdd; i++)
            {
                Cmd.Parameters["@customer_id"].Value = _customer_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Employee_id"].Value = _employee_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Product_id"].Value = _product_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@[Date]"].Value = _date;
                Cmd.Parameters["@[Amount_sold]"].Value = _amountSold;
                Cmd.Parameters["@[Unit_Price]"].Value = _unitPrice;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Total_Price"].Value = _totalPrice;
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

i searched the web sites but i couldn't find any thing usefull or similar to my problem

What should i do?

Comment: it appears that you're trying to insert a List<int> into a parameter that is expecting and integer. If what you're trying to do is bulk insert based off of lists, you should use the i iterator in the for loop as the index number to the list. `Cmd.Parameters["@Product_id"].Value = _product_Id[i];` is one example where a list<t> is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
        int RecordToAdd = _product_Id.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < RecordToAdd; i++)
        {
            Cmd.Parameters["@customer_id"].Value = _customer_Id;
            Cmd.Parameters["@Employee_id"].Value = _employee_Id;
            Cmd.Parameters["@Product_id"].Value = _product_Id;
            Cmd.Parameters["@[Date]"].Value = _date;
            Cmd.Parameters["@[Amount_sold]"].Value = _amountSold;
            Cmd.Parameters["@[Unit_Price]"].Value = _unitPrice;
            Cmd.Parameters["@Total_Price"].Value = _totalPrice;
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

To this:

```
        int RecordToAdd = _product_Id.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < RecordToAdd; i++)
        {
            Cmd.Parameters["@customer_id"].Value = _customer_Id;
            Cmd.Parameters["@Employee_id"].Value = _employee_Id;
            Cmd.Parameters["@Product_id"].Value = _product_Id[i];
            Cmd.Parameters["@[Date]"].Value = _date;
            Cmd.Parameters["@[Amount_sold]"].Value = _amountSold[i];
            Cmd.Parameters["@[Unit_Price]"].Value = _unitPrice[i];
            Cmd.Parameters["@Total_Price"].Value = _totalPrice[i];
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Notice in the second block I'm using the iterator of the loop to index which item in the list I'm inserting each time.

EDIT: Also, that connection_string you built doesn't look right. You might want to review it and correct any mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Change the "List<>" in FUNCTION PARAMETERS for Int32 or Integer.